# Pointers in C. Change the start of a list pointer by function

Tags: c, list, pointers

How can I make to change the start of a `list_pointer`?  I've tried to implement this by comparing two pointers. But it's only work inside one fuction.

Or I need to create new structure for exmple `struct entry head` ?

```
// Function to insert a new entry into a linked list. 
#include <stdio.h>

struct entry
{
    int            value;
    struct entry   *next;
};

void insertEntry(struct entry *insertion, struct entry *previous, struct entry *list_pointer)
{   //               1   <           100
    if (insertion->value < previous->value) {
        //         n0   =    n1
        insertion->next = previous;
        //           =  n0     // start from n0 insted of n1
        list_pointer = insertion;
        // list_pointer is set to point to n0 only here inside this fuction  
    }
    else {
        insertion->next = previous->next; // set n2_3.next to point to whatever n2.next was pointing to
        previous->next = insertion;       // set n2.next to point to n2_3
    }

}

void printPlist(struct entry *list_pointer)
{
    while (list_pointer != (struct entry *) 0) {
        printf("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    struct entry n3 = { .value = 300,.next = (struct entry *) 0 };
    struct entry n2 = { .value = 200,.next = &n3 };
    struct entry n1 = { .value = 100,.next = &n2 };
    struct entry *list_pointer = &n1;

    //struct entry n2_3 = { .value = 250 }; // insertion
    struct entry n0 = { .value = 1 }; // insertion

    printPlist(list_pointer);
    insertEntry(&n0, &n1, list_pointer);
    printPlist(list_pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list_pointer` is local to `insertEntry`. And modification to its value (which is an address) will not be reflected in the `list_pointer` that you defined in `main`.

As always you need to pass a pointer to the variable you wish to modify. If the variable is a pointer, it needs to be a pointer to a pointer:

```
void insertEntry(struct entry *insertion, struct entry *previous, struct entry **p_list_pointer)
{   //               1   <           100
    if (insertion->value < previous->value) {
        //         n0   =    n1
        insertion->next = previous;
        //           =  n0     // start from n0 insted of n1
        *p_list_pointer = insertion;
        // list_pointer is set to point to n0 only here inside this fuction  
    }
    else {
        insertion->next = previous->next; // set n2_3.next to point to whatever n2.next was pointing to
        previous->next = insertion;       // set n2.next to point to n2_3
    }

}
```

I omitted the check for NULL on `p_list_pointer`, but that's the gist of it.